# Creating QuickFixed file to apply QuickFixes via diff

Tags: macro, quickfix

**TL;DR** I have macros in each `%m` captured by `errorformat` after `:make`.  I'd like to have a copy of the file in another split and apply all the macros (so to have a fixed file) and then do a `:windo diffthis` to let the user (mostly me) to choose to `diffget` the fixed code or not.

**Question:** I am planning to do `ggyG` and then `:vnew P` then do a recursive macro call until I exhausted all `:cnext`.  However the error after exhaustion would stop the whole process which the `:windo diffthis` cannot start.  Is there a way to overcome this?

---

**Background**

To streamline my daily workflow, I'd like to have the Quick Fix Window not only to show where the errors are, but to suggest a way to quick fix.

Assuming that I have customized `makeprg` and `errorformat`, such that `errorformat` has `%m` capturing a `vi` macro that would fix the issue when run.

For example if I am working with jQuery and has this in line 1:

`var top = $element.top;`

`:make` will capture this and `errorformat` knows that `%l` is 1 and `%m` would be `1G/\.top<cr>i.offset()<esc>` (when run, would correctly insert `offset()` before `.top`)

Currently I am like using `:nnoremap Z <C-w><C-w>f<space>ly$<C-w><C-w>:@0<cr>` so after I did `:cnext` I can use `Z` to apply the fix.

I'd like to make `vi` smarter so `vi` could get me a fixed version of the code and I could check if `vi` 's suggestions are acceptable or not.  Therefore I asked the question.

By the way I am also interested in how Fugitive managed to create buffers that starts with `fugitive://` and there are no warning if I just run `:q`.

Comment: `:help 'buftype'`